# Cable from laptop brick to wall

Tags: laptop, power-supply, adapter, voltage

I've seen plenty of questions asked about the power output of laptop bricks to the laptop - however my question is does the plug and cable that runs from the laptop brick to the wall need to match up?

My laptop brick has the following spec:

Input: 100-240v 
Output: 19v, 2.1A

The only cable I can find anywhere that will fit this has the following spec:

Voltage: 10A 250V

Is this likely to cause any damage?

Would be most grateful for any advice.

Cheers.

Comment: @CharlieRB I would say no, since this is specifically referring to the current rating and that question doesn't address this issue (even though it should).

Answer (score 2):

The "10A, 250V" rating on the cable simple states what the cable can handle. This is not what it outputs. Current is not forced to the AC adapter ("brick"), it will only draw the current it needs.

Therefore, as stated in the possible duplicate question's answer in the comments, if the plug fits properly and with the proper plug configuration, it will not cause any damage.

Answer (score -2):

I just want to confirm-- you intend to replace ONLY the cable between the power brick and the wall. You will leave the same power brick in place. Using a power brick with an output of 10A with a computer with a requirement of 2.1A will cause massive damage. The power cable between the wall and the brick, on the other hand, does not draw in and of itself, as the answer above says.